# Java Hibernate - OneToMany relationship returning a null object (annotations)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, dropwizard

I'm currently struggling with a mapping of one to many using annotations in hibernate, whenever I get an object, the set of items returned from the related table is always null (even when I can see in the database there are corresponding relationships with data). I have some many to one relationships in the same class which are working fine.

Other unrelated code omitted for readability

I have two tables, where a single member, can have 0 or more member membership periods:

```
CREATE TABLE member (
    member_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY (member_id)
)

CREATE TABLE member_membership_period (
    member_membership_period_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    member_id INT NOT NULL ,
    test_column VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (member_membership_period_id) ,
    INDEX member_membership_period_member_idx (member_id ASC) ,
    CONSTRAINT member_membership_period_member
        FOREIGN KEY (member_id)
        REFERENCES member (member_id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

The Member class maps to the member table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="member")
public class Member implements Serializable  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "member_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "member_membership_period_member")
    private Set<MemberMembershipPeriod> memberMembershipPeriods = new HashSet<MemberMembershipPeriod>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<MemberMembershipPeriod> getMemberMembershipPeriods() {
        return memberMembershipPeriods;
    }

    public void setMemberMembershipPeriods(Set<MemberMembershipPeriod> memberMembershipPeriods) {
        this.memberMembershipPeriods = memberMembershipPeriods;
    }
}
```

And the MemberMembershipPeriod class maps to the member_membership_period table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="member_membership_period")
public class MemberMembershipPeriod implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "member_membership_period_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "test_column")
    String testColumn;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTestColumn() {
        return testColumn;
    }

    public void setTestColumn(String testColumn) {
        this.testColumn = testColumn;
    }
}
```

My DAO

```
public class MemberDaoImpl extends AbstractDAO<Member> implements MemberDao {

    public MemberDaoImpl(SessionFactory factory) {
       super(factory);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Member> getAllMembers() {
        Query query = currentSession().createQuery("from Member");
        return list(query);
    }

    @Override
    public Member getMemberById(int id) {
        return get(id);
    }
}
```

Implementation of get(id) (Part of drop wizards hibernate package)

```
protected E get(Serializable id) {
    return (E) currentSession().get(entityClass, checkNotNull(id));
}
```

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated, I'm starting to lose the will to live over this!

Other tech being used is DropWizard (which does the hibernate configuration) and MySQL

Comment: Well you have a JoinColumn with no name. I don't know what effect that will have. ForeignKey is only for DDL generation. Specify the name for JoinColumn.

Comment: Tried with the name on the join column, still getting null.

Comment: Okay, the mapping looks fine so can you post the code which loads the Entity?

Comment: I've added my DAO, completely forgot about that. Would i need to add the relationship in there? (Although I didnt need to for my ManyToOne relationships).

Comment: How are you loading for the failing test? getById or getAll()? Please show the implementation for get(id);

Comment: I've tested both methods, however the failing tests are functional tests which are going through a JAX-RS interface provided by DropWizard (which is also managing the hibernate configuration). However the JAX-RS resource is calling a service which calls the DAO, so I can add them but I don't think it will demonstrate much.

Comment: You need to show the superclass implementation of this return get(id);

Comment: Added above. The get method used by that method is org.hibernate.Session.get()

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

```
@Override
    public List<Member> getAllMembers() {
        Criteria criteria = currentSession().createCriteria(Member.class,"member");
        criteria.createAlias("member.memberMembershipPeriods","period");
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        return criteria.list();
    }
```